# Question About Particular Library's Usefulness

Tags: discussion, questions

If I have a question regarding a particular library's usefulness for performing a particular task is that considered in the scope of SO?  Should this type of question be asked on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)?

For example:  "I'm attempting to perform X and I know that this can be done using ABC's library, but I have some requirements that need to be fulfilled.  Will this library actually help the performance/usability/goal of my program, or end up hurting/loss of readability/etc in the long run?"

It can look like fishing for a library recommendation, but isn't exactly what the question is really asking.  What is the consensus on this type of question?

Comment: I'm inclined to say such a question would not be well-received on Stack Overflow. I'm not sure about the standards on Programmers.SE.

Comment: @icktoofay Even if it can produce an objective answer?

Comment: @JNYRanger that sounds very opinion based.

Comment: The question you are showing in your question (!) appears to me to have the fault of being opinion-based since "best" means different things to different people. Also, as I see it, even if your question is not saying directly "find me a library", negative answers will most likely offer other libraries. So it is inviting recommendations. (Like icktoofay I'm speaking from the SO standpoint. I don't know about Programmers.)

Comment: I think "best way to do it" was a poor choice of words, I'm going to edit my original question.

Comment: This sounds more like a code review type of question than a programmers question.

Comment: Changed the example question to make it more clear what I'm asking.  I want the question to produce an objective answer, but it's still a bit questionable for SO, hence why I'm asking here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you are absolutely correct. Anything asking "best X" is probably a bad choice for SO.

Comment: You know what I do in this situation?  Prototype.  Doesn't take that long, and you get better feedback than some random internet bot's opinion.